# how to define variable in phalcon php volt blade and assign data to it?

Tags: phalcon, volt

i have a variable in my blade that its set to the blade in controller

$this->view->->setVar("formData", $formData);

my formData is an array from my submitted form

now i want to define a new variable in? my volt blade and assign my formData to it.
how should i do that?

i read phalcon(https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/volt) volt document but i cant find how should i do that.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller `setVar()` and `setVars()` can be used on the `view` object to set your variables and then use them in your Volt file:

```
$this->view->setVar('myData', $data);
```

and in the template

```
{{ myData }}
```

If `$data` is an array and you want elements from it:

```
{{ myData['element1'] }}
```

If `$data` is an object you can call methods on it

```
{{ myData.myMethod() }}
```

If you want to perform comparisons and assign variables in the template:

```
{% if myData['element'] == 'yes' %}
    {% assign reply = true %}
{% else %}
    {% assign reply = false %}
{% endif %}
```

References:

https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/volt#variables

https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/volt#assignments

https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/volt#if